# C++ How can I initialize array of structs to null and later check if an element of this array is null in a while loop?

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, queue

I'm trying to write a queue implementation using a circular array in C++. I got that part right but my assignment asks me to print the Queue in a function in main.cpp. This poses a problem for me because I will have to print it in a while loop and the size of the queue is not necessarily it's max size at compile time.

For example: if the user enqueues 2 passengers in a queue that has max size 3, and I want to print the passengers in the queue, I'll have to let the while loop go on for only 2 iterations. But I am not allowed to pass the size of the queue so the only way I can do this is check if the passenger structs in the queue are not NULL. I don't know what NULL means within the context of structs.

This is my header file CQueue.h.

```
const int MAX = 3;

struct Passenger {
    char name[80];
};

class CQueue {
private:
    int front;
    int rear;
    Passenger passengers[MAX];

public:
    CQueue();
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    void Enqueue(Passenger);
    Passenger Front(); // Returns the passenger type at the front index of array
    void Dequeue();
};
```

This is my class constructor in CQueue.cpp

```
CQueue::CQueue() // Custom constructor initializes the fields of the CQueue class with the appropriate values
{
    front = -1; // Conditions for emptiness of CQueue
    rear = -1; // Conditions for emptiness of CQueue
    ??? // needs a line to initialize passengers[MAX] elements to some default NULL value
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to do in my main.cpp. I'm trying to print the Queue elements in order, but only the ones that have been inputted by the user. In other words, I don't want to print the empty elements.

```
while (???) // check if passanger is not the default null value
    {
        cout << CQueue.Front() << "\n";
        copyQueue.Dequeue();
    }
```

I'm uncertain what I should put in the place of ???. I've tried a bunch of different methods but it boils down to the simple fact that I don't know what a NULL value for a struct is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question? Put the question in the subject so it's easier for others to quickly see if they can help you, and understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passengers array is an array of objects, not an array of pointers, so you can't have a "NULL" passenger. But instead of changing them to pointers, a much cleaner design would be to figure out a count of passengers in your CQueue and use that to check if passengers are "the default value". Something like:

```
bool CQueue::IsEmpty() { return rear != -1 && front != -1; }
bool CQueue::IsFull() { return rear - front >= MAX; }
```

And then:

```
CQueue::CQueue() // Custom constructor initializes the fields of the CQueue class with the appropriate values
{
    front = -1; // Conditions for emptiness of CQueue
    rear = -1; // Conditions for emptiness of CQueue
}
```

And:

```
while (!copyQueue.IsEmpty())
{
    cout << CQueue.Front() << "\n";
    copyQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: Great idea! But I'm limited by the constraints of the assignment. I am not allowed to alter the CQueue class. Can you elaborate on the pointer method?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you can't change the class, I think you're supposed to use the front and rear members to figure out the count of passengers and implement Enqueue, Dequeue, IsEmpty and IsFull accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I had the methods correctly implemented in CQueue class, but it didn't occur to me to use IsEmpty() in the while loop condition. It worked!